# string interpolation broken with recent gsubfn?

Tags: r, debugging, gsub, string-interpolation

The last example used to work, and now it doesn't.  No string interpolation inside a function?   Maybe it has something to do with variable scope?   Any suggestions?

```
library(gsubfn)
#R.Version() # I'm using 2.15.0, just upgraded from 2.13.something.

### dumb example of a function
g <- function() {for (a in 1:2) { print(paste('is a', a)) }}
g()

### same thing, outside a function, using string interpolation
for (a in 1:2) { fn$print('is a $a') }
rm(a)

### and now string interpolation inside a function
h <- function() {for (a in 1:2) { fn$print('is a $a') }}
h()
```

This last example is telling me

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found
```

Comment: See June 24th news item on the gsubfn package home page: http://gsubfn.googlecode.com#NEWS

Comment: Thanks to Gabor for clarifying--I just took the liberty of editing the question title as this is not a bug in *R* but rather in an add-on package.